# Modifying dictionary that contains a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert:
This Diciotonary :

```
dictio = {(3, 3): 'blue'}
```

to

```
dictio = {33: 'blue'}
```

I have no trouble modifying the dict value but the tuple key is the issue.

Seeing that the tuple cannot be modified, how should I go about this?

Comment: You shouldn't modify *any* dictionary key in place. Add the value under the new key and delete the old key. It would be helpful to give a [mcve] of exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Or instead of modifying `dictio`, build a new dict.

Comment: Even if you *could* modify a tuple, you couldn't turn it into an `int`.

Comment: `c = { (5,55):"Hello", (55,5):"World") }` ... your aproach: Problem - Key-collision

Comment: Building new dictionary, is what i have been trying but cant seem to wrap my head around the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
dictio = {int(''.join(map(str, k))): v for k,v in dictio.items()}
```

Returns:

```
{33: 'blue'}
```

This also works for the following example:

```
dictio = {(3, 3): 'blue', (4, 2): 'red', (6, 2, 5): 'green'}
```

Returns:

```
{33: 'blue', 42: 'red', 625: 'green'}
```

Be mindful that this will result in key collision if you have a case such as `{(4, 31): 'red', (43, 1): 'green'}`, and your result will include the last key-value pair, in this case `{431: 'green'}`.

In that case, I would instead use the following:

```
dictio = {(3, 3): 'blue', (4, 2): 'yellow', (4, 31): 'red', (43, 1): 'green'}

new_dict = {}
for k,v in dictio.items():
    key = int(''.join(map(str, k)))
    if key in new_dict:
        new_dict[key].append(v)
    else:
        new_dict[key] = [v]
```

Returns:

```
{33: ['blue'], 42: ['yellow'], 431: ['red', 'green']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read out the keys of the first dict, format the tuple values separately by using the 0 and 1 indexes, then assign those and the value to the new dict.

Can be done in one line with dictio as...

```
dictio = {(3,3):"blue", (5,5):"red"}
```

Then...

```
newDict = {int("{}{}".format(x[0],x[1])):v for x,v in dictio.items()}
```

Returns...

```
>>>{33: 'blue', 55: 'red'}
```

This works because we are saying that "dictio.items()" contains the key:value pair which can be referred to as X and V respectively. NewDict should be comprised of the first part of the key (x[0]) formatted next to the second part of the key (x[1]) paired with the previous unchanged value.

Comment: The questioner wants `33`, not `'33'`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a general solution to your problem:

```
dictio = {(3, 3): 'blue'}


dictio = {int("".join([str(e) for e in key])): dictio[key] for key in dictio.keys()}
```

output:

```
>>> dictio
{33: 'blue'}
```

Comment: Adding or removing keys in a dict during iteration is unsafe and may lead to skipped or double-processed keys. Also `type(key) == type(tuple())` is a terrible way to test whether something is a tuple; `isinstance(key, tuple)` would be a better check, or `type(key) is tuple` if you need an exact type match.

Comment: Also, the questioner wants `33`, not `'33'`.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I edited my answer.
Can you please explain why it is unsafe? I didn't know. @user2357112

Comment: Adding or removing keys can trigger a rebuild of the dict, moving everything around and changing the size of the underlying hash table. Also, depending on details of hash codes and Python versions, new keys added may end up on either side of the current iteration position. Python makes a bit of an effort to detect this, by throwing an error if it detects that a dict has changed size during iteration, but adding and removing the same number of keys prevents the check from functioning.

Comment: thank you, this is interesting, i'll edit my answer then @user2357112

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm to convert your tuple to an integer:

```
dictio = {(3, 3): 'blue'}

dictio = {sum(j*10**i for i, j in enumerate(k)): v for k, v in dictio.items()}

print(dictio)

{33: 'blue'}
```

Alternatively, if your tuples are always of size 2, you can use f-strings with `int`:

```
dictio = {int(f'{k[0]}{k[1]}'): v for k, v in dictio.items()}
```

Of course, you should be careful there are no clashes with either algorithm: the first would fail for `(1, 0)` vs `(0, 10)`. The latter would fail for `(12, 3)` vs `(1, 23)`. In the case of a clash, it's not clear what you require.